# Non-recursive Quicksort in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to work on a non-recursive version of quicksort in scala but whenever I try to implement it, I get stuck and end up using tail recursion. Is there any simple way to implement Quicksort without the use of recursion in Scala?

All help is appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: The recursive solution has been added. In this solution the sortingHelper method is tail-recursive.

```
def quickSortRecursive(values: Array[Int]) {
  // Swap the elements so that they aren't impacting recursion performance.
  // This swap helps the pivot get the correct position.
  def swap(i: Int, j: Int) {
    val t = values(i);
    values(i) = values(j);
    values(j) = t
  }

  // A method that takes in lower and upper bounds then sorts them.
  def sortRange(lowerBound: Int, upperBound: Int): (Int, Int) = {
    // Establish the pivot for use in sorting the bounds
    val pivot = values((lowerBound + upperBound) / 2)
    var i = lowerBound
    var j = upperBound

    // Sort the bounds using the pivot
    while (i <= j) {
      while (values(i) < pivot) {
        i += 1
      }
      while (values(j) > pivot) {
        j -= 1
      }
      if (i <= j) {
        swap(i, j)
        i += 1
        j -= 1
      }
    }

    // After the swaps, return the segments as lower and upper bounds
    (i, j)
  }

  @tailrec
  def sortingHelper(segments: List[(Int, Int)]) {
    // Take in the tuples from sortRange and sort them using tail-recursion
    segments.head match {
      case (l, r) =>
        var newSegments = segments.tail

        sortRange(l, r) match {
          case (i, j) =>
            if (l < j) {
              newSegments = (l, j) :: newSegments
            }
            if (i < r) {
              newSegments = (i, r) :: newSegments
            }
        }
        if (newSegments.nonEmpty) {
          sortingHelper(newSegments)
        }
    }
  }

  sortingHelper(List((0, values.length - 1)))
}
```

Comment: Before this gets marked as a stupid question, I have tried looking up some more information about this and couldn't come across a non-recursive implementation of quicksort in Scala.

Comment: Any tail recursion can fairly trivially be rewritten as a while loop. Not sure why that's really necessary though.

Comment: As @Jasper-M has pointed out... any tail recursive solution can be easily converted to a loop based solution. Can you share your attempts at doing this ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I have written a tail-recursive solution but I cannot seem to convert it into a loop like Jasper mentioned. Please look at my edited question for my recursive solution. The sortingHelper method is tail-recursive.

Comment: And where is that edited question ? Also, what is the exact problem in you loop like implementation ? Are you trying with `immutable` `val`'s ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Check now. I just need to turn my solution OR find another solution that does QuickSort in Scala without recursion since my solution already uses recursion. I want 2 versions: a recursive quicksort and a non-recursive quicksort in scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the implementation itself needs huge improvements and I hope that will come as you improve with Scala. I will assume that everything else is perfect and just focus on conversion from tail-recursive.

To convert tail-recursive code to loop-based, you just have to capture the recursion-termination condition and make it the loop termination condition,

```scala
def sortingHelper2(segments: List[(Int, Int)]): Unit = {
  var newSegments = segments
  while (newSegments.nonEmpty) {
    val (l, r) = newSegments.head
    newSegments = newSegments.tail
    sortRange(l, r) match {
      case (i, j) =>
        if (l < j) {
          newSegments = (l, j) :: newSegments
        }
        if (i < r) {
          newSegments = (i, r) :: newSegments
        }
    }
  }
}
```

To better explain, lets look at one of the simplest tail-recursive functions,

```scala
def sumUpToN(n: Int): Long = {
  @tailrec
  def _sumUpToN(acc: Long, m: Int): Long = {
    if (m > 0)
      _sumUpToN(acc + m, m - 1)
    else
      acc
  }

  _sumUpToN(0, n)
}
```

To convert it to a loop based one, you just have to move this termination/continuation condition to your while loop,

```scala
def sumUpToN(n: Int): Long = {
  var acc = 0
  var m = n

  while (m > 0) {
    acc = acc + m
    m = m - 1
  }

  acc
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for your help! I just started learning Scala in my university computer science classes 2 weeks ago so this implementation is disgusting, I know. I did come up with a recursive solution that took me 8 lines in total but it didn't have the performance benefits of tail recursion like this solution. Thank you so much once again! Would you recommend any Scala resources? P.S: I appreciate your Yordle Pantheon avatar from LoL!